# DRBD with external meta disk

Tags: ubuntu, drbd

I am attempting to create a failover with DRBD and I have two partitions.

Partition 1) /dev/sda4 is setup for the KVMs I will be creating.
Partition 2) /dev/sda5 is for the DRBD metadata

My config file is below

```
resource r0 {
    protocol C;
    startup {
            wfc-timeout  15;
            degr-wfc-timeout 60;
    }
    net {
            cram-hmac-alg sha1;
            shared-secret "SECRET_KEY";
    }
    on Server1{
            device /dev/drbd0;
            disk /dev/sda4;
            address IP:7788;
            meta-disk /dev/sda5;
    }
    on Server2{
            device /dev/drbd0;
            disk /dev/sda4;
            address IP:7788;
            meta-disk /dev/sda5;
    }
```

}

When I run drbdadm create-md r0 it runs successfully but it creates /dev/drbd0 on both partitions.

```
    ├─sda4      8:4    0  7.2T  0 part
    │ └─drbd0 147:0    0  7.2T  1 disk
    └─sda5      8:5    0  399M  0 part
      └─drbd0 147:0    0  7.2T  1 disk
```

It's my understanding that it should only create it on the meta disk which is /dev/sda5.  The reason I setup the meta disk is to avoid any writing to sda4. Am I correct in that reasoning or am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out. By putting the volume group on top of DRBD0 everything is now working.

I did run into a problem when creating a volume group on the device and had to add filter to lvm.conf

I got an error that said

```
Cannot use device /dev/drbd/ with duplicates
```

I just added the this to the devices section

```
filter = [ "r|/dev/sda4|", "r|/dev/disk/|", "r|/dev/block/|", "a/.*/" ]
```

Everything works great now

Comment: Layering LVM on top of DRBD didn't change anything meaningful. You could have used it the way it was, since there were no issues the way you had it. It's more common to put LVM underneath DRBD so it's easier to grow the device later. Also, you'll have to activate/deactivate the VGs on failover with this setup.

Comment: There was an issue the way I had it. It didn't work. I could not create an LVMs in the way it was setup

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed this is how `lsblk` output looks on AlmaLinux 8.5 when using external meta-data with DRBD. The DRBD device is only a single virtual block device layered over both partitions in your setup.

It works as expected. If you inspect the block devices using other methods/utilities you'll see that you only have a single `/dev/drbd0`, and the metadata partition you created is the size you'd expect.

For example, my configuration using two LVM volumes:

```
resource r0 {
    protocol C;
    startup {
            wfc-timeout  15;
            degr-wfc-timeout 60;
    }
    net {
            cram-hmac-alg sha1;
            shared-secret "SECRET_KEY";
    }
    on Server1{
            device /dev/drbd0;
            disk /dev/drbdpool/data;      # 1GiB lvm on /dev/sdb
            meta-disk /dev/drbdpool/meta; # 4MiB lvm on /dev/sdb
            192.168.1.11:7788;
    }
    on Server2{
            device /dev/drbd0;
            disk /dev/drbdpool/data;      # 1GiB lvm on /dev/sdb
            meta-disk /dev/drbdpool/meta; # 4MiB lvm on /dev/sdb
            192.168.1.12:7788;
    }
```

Shows exactly what I'd expect in `/proc/partitions`:

```
# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0   20480000 sda
   8        1    2048000 sda1
   8        2   18430976 sda2
   8       16    8388608 sdb
 253        0       4096 dm-0
 253        1    1048576 dm-1
 147        0    1048576 drbd0
```

`blockdev --report` looks good too:

```
# blockdev --report /dev/drbd0
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0      1073741824   /dev/drbd0
# blockdev --report /dev/drbdpool/meta 
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw  8192   512  4096          0         4194304   /dev/drbdpool/meta
# blockdev --report /dev/drbdpool/data
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw  8192   512  4096          0      1073741824   /dev/drbdpool/data
```

This is likely where `lsblk` is getting confused:

```
# cat /sys/block/drbd0/size 
2097152
# cat /sys/block/dm-0/size 
8192
# cat /sys/block/dm-1/size 
2097152
# cat /sys/block/dm-0/holders/drbd0/size 
2097152
# cat /sys/block/dm-1/holders/drbd0/size 
2097152
```

Comment: OK...then I am confused as to why DRB0 is taking up the entire disk of SDA4. For some reason it is allocated 7.2T. Why is that if the metadata is supposed to be on SDA5?

Comment: You configured DRBD to do that by setting `disk /dev/sda4;`. This is how DRBD works: You give an entire disk/partition to DRBD, and then you use the resulting DRBD device just as you would any other disk/partition. I assume you're going to want to format `/dev/drbd0` with whatever filesystem you want to use and `mount /dev/drbd0 /var/lib/libvirt/images`, or wherever you configured libvirt to store your VM images. Since you've mounted the DRBD device, everything you write into that mount point will be replicated to the peer via the DRBD device. DRBD's metadata is on `/dev/sda5`...

Comment: OK...That makes sense. I assumed that DRB0 and the VMs would reside side by side on SDA4 but what you are saying is that any data I use needs to be on top of DRBD0 correct?